# Spring + Kerberos + trusted domains

Tags: java, spring, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

I have 2 domains in Active Directory: domain A and domain B. There is a bidirectional trust set up between those domains. Domain A has a user A, domain B has a user B. Additionally domain A has a domain local security group called group A. User B is a member of group A.

What I want to achieve is to authenticate both users in domain A. So far I had no problems with authenticating user A in domain A and user B in domain B. Now I need to authenticate user B in domain A.

Is this doable in Java/Spring tech stack? My first try was with ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider from Spring Security, but then I checked that it uses simple ldap bind request, so I guess this is not doable with this provider.

Next I tried to use Kerberos (Spring Security Kerberos module), but again: I can authenticate user A in domain A and user B in domain B. No success when trying to authenticate user B in domain A. When I read some topics regarding cross-realm authentication in Kerberos, I can see solutions with two realms (each has its own KDC specified). This will work in a way that user B will be authenticated in domain B, which I want to avoid.

My krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = DOMAIN-A.COM
    default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = true
[realms]
    DOMAIN-A.COM = {
        kdc = domain-a.com
        admin_server = domain-a.com
    }
[domain_realm]
    .domain-a.com = DOMAIN-A.COM
    domain-a.com = DOMAIN-A.COM
```

Is there any way I can configure Kerberos (or maybe Configure Active Directory or KDC) to make it happen?

Or some completely another approach to this problem? Like something else than Kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

You're OK on the "User B is a member of the domain local security group A" part.  But what I think is wrong is your krb5.conf doesn't contain any references to domain B. So it won't know where to go to validate the Kerberos ticket. See an [MIT example of an krb5.conf containing two domains](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Sample-krb5_002econf-File.html). If it still doesn't work after editing the krb5.conf according to the example please update your question with what the latest one looks like.

Comment: I tried to add a second realm (for DOMAIN-B.COM) to krb5.conf and it worked. But then when authenticating with user B a connection to DOMAIN-B.COM host was set-up. I want to avoid this and create connections only to DOMAIN-A.COM host.
In the meantime, I asked my colleague to check if it works in .NET. He just created a very simple command line app using following code
`PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sNetBiosName)
context.ValidateCredentials(sUsername, sPassword)`

Comment: from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace. It works like a charm - I just give "DOMAIN-A.COM" as a dnsName and try with many different users (I just give usernames, without '@DOMAIN-A.COM' or '@DOMAIN-B.COM' suffix) and it works correctly. No matter if given user exists in DOMAIN-A or DOMAIN-B. In every case the user is authenticated and what is more important I always connect to host DOMAIN-A.COM only (and I don't specify in what domain user exists, so it recognizes the correct domain automatically).

Comment: I have checked with Wireshark that this app uses NTLM protocol. Maybe this is the right way to go? But then I have read that Spring Security does not support NTLM anymore and Spring recommends to use Kerberos. Is the same achievable in Kerberos? If not, maybe someone can suggest another solution in Java - the best would be something in Spring, but at the end every solution in Java is fine for me.

Comment: Ah.  Glad to know it's working with NTLM.  It appears the fallback to NTLM may have come into play because there was no SPN in place for your service running in Domain A.  In Kerberos, when no SPN is found, fallback to NTLM will occur if Kerberos authentication type is not available.  Since you didn't place it in your question, can you give an example of the service the clients are accessing?  Is it HTTP or some other?  Also provide the FQDN too, or at least an obfuscation of it so that you and I know we're talking about the same thing going forward.

Comment: The client is accessing the web application and communicates through HTTPS protocol. I tried to check with some SPN - I added user X in DOMAIN-A.COM, then created SPN like HTTPS/testapp.com@DOMAIN-A.COM and generated keytab. Then I set up a Kerberos client in Spring using keytab file (I did not use krb5.conf in this case). In this configuration Kerberos authenticated succesfully.

Comment: But do I understand correctly, that keytab has encrypted password inside and can be used in a scenario when I will authenticate my app automatically to Active Directory server? I don't want to do it - I just want to prompt a user for its username and password with a simple form. Thus I just removed keytab and implementation using this keytab and switched to another implementation, where I use SunJaasKerberosClient that works with username and password.

Comment: Maybe I should somehow combine those two implementations? I mean use keytab to automatically authenticate my app and then prompt user for its username and password and try to authentiate? But how can it work? I thought that there is nothing like session maintained when connectin to Active Directory right? So every next call to AD server will have no context and will be just another separate call? Sorry for dumb questions, but I'm very new to both Active Directory and Kerberos.

Comment: When you use a keytab, with correct configuration user is not prompted for authentication and will never be - that is Kerberos SSO.  You're right Active Directory is stateless and does not track session state - that's the client responsibility.  Successful Kerberos authentication results in client obtaining a service ticket good for 10 hours by default - and will therefore *not* have to re-auth in that time period.  If you want to prompt user for username and password don't use Kerberos - use LDAP instead.  Note however LDAP will result in *many* more auth calls back to Active Directory.

Comment: If you want to use the Java stack with Kerberos and prompt for the password, all you need is a plugin for JAAS that will ask for the password.  A Kerberos session will be initiated by the JAAS login module after the password is validated.

Comment: That is exactly what I have right now. I use the class SunJaasKerberosClient from Spring Security, but as I said it works only for simple scenario - when I authenticate user A i domain A. When I want to authenticate user B in domain B - it doesn't work. I don't use a keytab file here.

My first try was without Kerberos. I used ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider (it uses LDAP protocol), but again only simple scenario worked. The reason is this provider uses simple bind request - I read that using simple bind Active directory will not allow the user to trusted domain.

Comment: Any idea how can I make it happen?

Comment: I need to think about this one.  I don't have time to reproduce right now.